# Water filtering through staircase and flooding basement

Tags: basement, leak, stairs, cement

This staircase was recently renovated. This is in the back of my house and takes you to the basement. I noticed that when it rains a lot water starts filtrating through the stairs and end up wetting my basement. Any ideas why the water is entering through the last two stairs and what can be done to stop it.

[image]

Comment: Usually the best type of repair will be from the outside.  Possible just fixing grade so water runs away from the house, but most times it means digging down and sealing the leak.  Any downspouts near there should be fixed so water is taken away, 10 plus feet.

Comment: This is an outdoor stairway? That's a retaining wall to the right? What was the scope of work performed? You're very familiar with the "before" state, where you can confirm with certainty that the water infiltration is a consequence of the work performed?

Comment: You need to remove the water before it gets to the stairs. Intercept and direct elsewhere.